# Python: Speed up encryption of a list

Tags: python, list, encryption

I am using python to encrypt a list of strings. However it takes way to long (0.045 sec/list). Am I making any big misstakes that make my code run slow. 
Here is the code:

```
row=['string1', 'string2','string3','string4','string5','string6','string7','string8','string9']

from pyDes import *
import time

def encode(data,password):
    k = des(password, CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
    d = k.encrypt(data)
    return d

start=time.time()
for idx, val in enumerate(row):
    row[idx]=encode(str(val).encode(), 'password')

end=time.time()    
print(end-start)
```

In reality the list is much longer (~33) and is a combination of strings and ints.
Any tips on how to speed up the process. I would also consider using a difrent encryption is adviced.
Thank you!

Comment: did you try `row = list(map(encode, row))` ? Having said that, the encoding you use will be responsible most the vast majority of the computation time so just optimize that

Comment: For some reason that does not work, even if I hardcode the password in the encode function. I get an error when I try to make a list of the map object.

Comment: Ofc.. yeah sorry about that. You can work around this problem (using `partial` from `functools`) but this is will not have much effect if any. Concentrate on the encryption but I can't really suggest anything on that.

Answer (score 3):

Any pure-python implementation of a cipher will basically be dog slow. Python is made for many things, but fast bit ops is not one of them. That's why many interpreted languages use C/C++ implementations (or even hand-optimized assembly) of ciphers instead.

Try [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/) which [supports the AES-NI CPU instruction](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/src/AESNI.c) on reasonably recent Intel & AMD processors. Who knows, you may actually use a cipher implementation that cannot be hacked in a few minutes (like single DES with its key size of 56 bits).

Comment: With its bignum capabilities build right into the core language, Python is pretty easy for asymmetric primitives though. No language is easier for *experimenting* with RSA calculations

Comment: I tried PyCrypto but for some reason I would not get the decryption to work (no idea why). But thanks for the input, at least now I know that python is not the best way to do that task.